# pattern for saving newline-delimited json (aka linejson, jsonlines, .jsonl files) with python

Tags: python, json, line, newline, jsonlines

With Python, I'm saving json documents onto separate lines like this:

```
from bson import json_util # pymongo

with open('test.json', 'ab') as f:
    for document in documents:
       f.write(json_util.dumps(document)+'\n')
```

and then reading like this:

```
with open('test.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        document = json_util.loads(line)
```

The ease and simplicity make me think that there must be a gotcha? Is this all there is to linejson, aka [jsonlines](http://jsonlines.org/)?

Comment: Are you experiencing actual problems? Can the JSON contain newlines?

Comment: I'm trying to head off potential problems. I've tested it with json that contains newlines, and it seems to work fine. But I don't want to wake up a month from now and suddenly say: 'ohhh no'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's all there is to it.

Comment: For long runs: if it gets interrupted in the middle of a write, and then restarted, the file is then corrupt. Is there a pattern for validating on each open (since I'm appending)?

Comment: Not necessarily, but certainly that could happen. There are different ways you could handle that; the best depends on the details of your usage. One thing you could do is make sure the reader code ignores invalid lines. You could also open the file read/write and check the last line before continuing to append data.

Comment: Thank you. So: for my log-file-like case: open read/write - check for final newline - if not there, add - then make first new write. Then have a `try/except` in read code for catching invalid documents. The combination would limit the damage to just the interrupted document(s). Does that sound right?

Comment: Sounds about right, yes. You don't even have to lose the interrupted document; just don't mark it as having been written until after `f.write(...); f.flush()` complete successfully.